# Mismatch in the count of stop-words in `Defaults.stop_words` and the ones derived from `nlp.vocab`?

Tags: nlp, spacy, stop-words

Suppose we have `nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')`. When typing in `len(nlp.Defaults.stop_words)`, it returns `326`, but when I run the following code (essentially counting the stopwords of the vocabulary), I get `111`:

```
i=0
for word in nlp.vocab:
    if word.is_stop:
        print(word.text)
        i+=1
print(i)
```

Given that (presumably) both `Defaults.stop_words` and `nlp.vocab` work with the same underlying vocabulary loaded through `nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')`, I don't understand why the number mismatch. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual default list of stopwords that are used for checking if any token `is_stop` is obtained with `nlp.Defaults.stop_words`, so the list contains `326` words.

The mismatch derives from the fact that the `nlp.vocab` is a `Vocab` containing `Lexemes` (word-types) that are kept for different reasons such as improving efficiency and that gets updated with new entries while processing new documents. When you initialize the `Language` (`nlp`), the `Vocab` will contain a certain number of default entries (in my case `764`) and you will see this number increase when you process new documents with words actually present in your documents.

So, with the cycle in the example we are just checking if some of these default entries of the language `Vocab` are present on the list of stopwords which contains `326` words and which actually is `nlp.Defaults.stop_words`.